# XAMPP URL with 'error' end to 404 Not found

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, xampp

Is there some problem with URLs which have word `error` in them? Because if I enter route like http://eshop.local/controller/action, where controller can be anything at all, there's no problem, but if controller is error, it returns:

```
Error 404 Page not found
```

My htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

http://eshop.local/error works fine but if is followed by some  action whatever word, number, or anything returns `404` error.

**EDIT:**

Just now i have copied it to my webhosting, everything with error urls is working fine, so problem is on XAMPP side.

Comment: Please give us an example of a url you would like to put into the browser, and where it should redirect. Otherwise it's hard to understand your requirements. Thanks. :)

Comment: http://eshop.local/error/action should redirect me to index.pgp, where in $_GET['url'] = 'error/action', working on my webhosting, on my localhost XAMPP return 404 Not found

Comment: Does your xampp host has an `/error/` directory?

Comment: Well, it's weekend, so I'm not at home. I will try it as soon as I can :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Response from Altrea, Moderator from XAMPP forum:

```
All URLs that are used in an Alias, Location or Proxy definition.
There are a bunch of them in XAMPP Apache (depending on which config files are activated or not some of them are maybe not used):

/cgi-bin/
/error/
/examples
/icons/
/licenses
/manual
/my-gateway/
/phpmyadmin
/php-cgi/
/security
/server-info
/server-status
/uploads
/webalizer
/webdav

In your case /error/ is already useds
```

Is it possible to reuse for example that /error/ or it' s better to change it in my code for example to /err/ ?

```
This Alias is used for the default Apache 
error Pages (everywhere ErrorDocuemnt is used this Alias is used).
So it is possible to change it in XAMPP, but you have to 
search and replace multiple files.
```

Answer (score 0):

**Hold Your Breath**

- Open xampp control panel
- Stop Apache
- Click the `Config` button on the Apache row, and select `httpd.conf`
- In that file, search for `<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs">`
- A bit lower, you may see a line like this: `# AllowOverride All`. Remove the `#`, which is a comment
- Save the file
- Restart Apache, say a prayer, cross  your fingers and hold your breath

Comment: Ok, I tried, but it didn't helped. Still the same problem.